Next.js 14 with Apollo Client: GraphQL Fragments Not Working
I'm migrating the front-end of an Angular app to a Next.js app. We're using GraphQL to communicate with the backend. However, I'm facing an issue with using fragments in GraphQL queries/mutations.
Whenever I import a fragment and use it in a query or mutation, I get a request error. But if I hardcode the fragment directly into the query/mutation, it works perfectly. Interestingly, when I test the same fragment in Apollo Server, it also works without issues.
Here’s my setup:
Environment:
Framework: Next.js 14
Apollo Client: @apollo/client version ^3.11.10
Apollo Client Configuration:
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: process.env.GRAPHQL_URI || "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;

Mutation Example:
When I use the fragment in my mutation like this:
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { USER_FRAGMENT } from "../fragments/auth/user.fragment";

export const LOGIN_SOCIAL_MUTATION = gql`
  ${USER_FRAGMENT}
  mutation loginSocial($token: String!) {
    loginSocial(token: $token) {
      user {
        ...UserFragment
      }
      token
    }
  }
`;

Fragment:
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const USER_FRAGMENT = gql`
  fragment UserFragment on UserProfile {
    _id
    createdAt
    // other attributes
  }
`;

This throws a request error. However, if I hardcode the fragment directly into the mutation, like this:
export const LOGIN_SOCIAL_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation loginSocial($token: String!) {
    loginSocial(token: $token) {
      user {
        _id
        createdAt
        //other attributes
      }
      token
    }
  }
`;

It works fine.
Additional Information:
When I test the fragment directly in Apollo Server (e.g., via Apollo Sandbox), it works as expected.
Question: What could be causing this issue? How can I fix it so I can use fragments properly in queries/mutations without having to hardcode them?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Have you tried adding the _id to the user in the original mutation? Like
  mutation loginSocial($token: String!) {
    loginSocial(token: $token) {
      user {
        _id
        ...UserFragment

....

